# How to export a MXD to a PDF but only switching the folder

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy

Let say I have two variables.

```
    InputMXD = parameters[0].valueAsText
    PDF_Folder = parameters[1].valueAsText
```

I have my inputMXDs to have multivalues so I'll have around 10 mxds each time the script is run.  I want to put the exported pdf's into different directory, but I want to use whatever the mxd name is.  The input could be p:/mxds/oneexample.mxd and p:/mxds/onemoreexample.mxd and the output would be z:/pdfs/oneexample.pdf and p:/mxds/onemoreexample.pdf.

```
    MXDList = arcpy.ListFiles(InputMXD)
    for MXDPath in MXDList:
        MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDPath)
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(MXD, PDF_Folder + )
```

Here's what I have to get me to the last line.  I don't know how to add the original file name of the mxd to the outputted PDF.

---

Updated:  It will run through it, but it doesn't output anything.  The output folder is empty.  I think there's something wrong with the loop.  Here's what I now have in my loop.

```
    MXDList = arcpy.ListFiles(InputMXD)
    for MXDPath in MXDList:
        MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDPath)
        outputPDF = os.path.basename(MXDPath).split('.')[0] + ".pdf"
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(MXD, PDF_Folder + "\\" + outputPDF)
```

I tried the code below and still no dice.  Here's what the results kicked back.
[image]

I'm not sure why it's saying the output is empty?

---

Update 2:  I updated the code to this:

```
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    arcpy.env.workspace = PDF_Folder
    MXDList = arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd')
    for MXDPath in MXDList:
        MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDPath)
        outputPDF = os.path.basename(MXDPath).split('.')[0] + ".pdf"
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(MXD, PDF_Folder + "\\" + outputPDF)
```

I changed the workspace to PDF_Folder and it didn't kick back an error.  It also didn't output any PDF files.

Also, here's how my parameters are setup at the top.

```
    # First parameter
    InputMXD = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Input MXDs",
        name="InputMXD",
        datatype="DEMapDocument",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input",
        multiValue=True)

    # Second Parameter
    PDF_Folder = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Output Folder for PDF",
        name="PDF_Folder",
        datatype="DEFolder",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Output")
```

Does my output need to be something besides a DEFolder datatype?

---

Update 3

Here's what my input looks like:
[image]

Input MXDs is a MapDocument that is a multiValue input.
Output Folder for PDF is a DEFolder output.  I've tried strings, workspaces, folders.  Nothing has worked.  I know its something small making this really frustrating.  I'm going basic to see if I can get just one mxd outputted to a pdf.  Crawl before I can walk.

---

Update 4

I'm trying to run the command directly in ArcMap from the python window.  Here is the kickback it's giving me.
[image: Python Window in Arc]

---

Update 5

I have tried just running it in a small script to see if it worked with a file name.  It does and it includes spaces, commas, periods, dashes and underscores.  Here's the simple testing code that worked.  I have no idea what isn't working.

```
 import arcpy

 doc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Q://Field Data//6th P.M//COLORADO//6N65W//PROJECTS//6N-65W-12//HOLTON 6-65-12//BEP.mxd")
 arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(doc, "C://temp//test2.pdf")
```

Comment: Editted my answer below - need to set a workspace and then use the arcpy.ListFiles with a wildcard like below

Comment: I use typically use the arcpy.GetParameterAsText option to get my workspace and arguments

Comment: I thought you had to set the data type in python toolboxes

Comment: You can set the data type to String/Text and input it.  That will work too!

Comment: I've tried different data types, but I think it something else.  It's skipping over something.

Comment: I think it has something to do with derived outputs where they are the same name as you inputs...http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000028000000

Comment: just a wild stab, but have you tried this w/a map document whose pathname does not have any spaces? Seems like the function is failing attempting to validate the map document (`isinstance()`). Maybe it's not able to resolve the location?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try to get the PDF name based on the input MXD lists name:

```
import os
import arcpy
inws = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
outfolder = arcpy.GetParameter(1)
arcpy.env.workspace = inws
MXDList = arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd')
for MXDPath in MXDList:
    MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDPath)
    outputPDF = os.path.basename(MXDPath).split('.')[0] + ".pdf"
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(MXD, outfolder + "\\" + outputPDF)
```

The parameters for the toolbox should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Would that go inside the loop on a separate line?

Comment: You would have to re-initiate the outpdfname for each MXD - so inside the loop - so in your loops script - you would have to use the MXDPath for your input

Comment: Since it's a python toolbox, I don't have to deal with adding a script.  I've never dealt with that window.  All of that data is built in the script.

Comment: I have never approached it like this before - I don't know how to write that or impliment it.

Comment: No problem.  Here are the different data types for python toolboxes.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000035000000

Comment: Instead of using DEFolders can you use GPString?  Also - your first argument maybe shouldn't be an MXD - because you want all the MXD's in 1 folder - so it should be a string too?

Comment: The mxds are MapDocument data types so only MXDs can be added to the data.  I tried all of them with strings and it passes, but doesn't output anywhere still.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the def execute code from my python toolbox.

```
    # Get inputs
    InputMXD = parameters[0].valueAsText
    PDF_Folder = parameters[1].valueAsText
    printer = parameters[2].valueAsText

    # Set workspace as defined by user
    env.workspace = InputMXD

    #List Names for Inputs
    arcpy.AddMessage("PDF Folder: "+PDF_Folder)
    arcpy.AddMessage("MXDs before Loop: "+InputMXD)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Printer: "+printer)

    for MXDPath in parameters[0].valueAsText.split(';'):
        #This part outputs to PDF
        arcpy.AddMessage("LOOPING.." + MXDPath)
        outputPDF = os.path.basename(MXDPath).split('.')[0] + ".pdf"
        arcpy.AddMessage("OutputPDF name is: " + outputPDF)
        MXDDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(MXDPath)
        arcpy.AddMessage("PDF Path: "+ PDF_Folder + "\\" + outputPDF)
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(MXDDoc, PDF_Folder + "\\" + outputPDF)
        #This part Prints to a certain printer
        arcpy.mapping.PrintMap(MXDDoc, printer)
```